# Numerical Approximation of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the differential equation that models the velocity of a falling object:
$$ \frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{c}{m}v^2 - g $$

Where:

- c= drag coefficient = constant
- m = mass
- g = acceleration due to gravity

The purpose of the problem is to approximate this using the fact:
$$ \frac{dv}{dt} \approx \frac{v(x_i) - v(x_{i-1})}{\Delta x} $$

Substituting this back into the original problem I get:

$$\frac{v(x_i) - v(x_{i-1})}{\Delta x} = \frac{c}{m} v(x_i)^2 - g $$

Then I rearrange the formula for $v(x_i)$ and complete the square to get:

$$ v(x_i) = \sqrt{ \frac{m^2}{4 \cdot c \cdot \Delta x} + \frac{g \cdot m}{c} - \frac{v(x_{i-1}) \cdot m} {2\cdot c \cdot \Delta x} } + \frac{m}{2 \cdot c \cdot h}$$

Now I am trying to automate this in excel using the following constants:

- $\Delta x = 1$
- c= 0.125
- m= 100.19
- g= 9.81
- Initial condition: $v(0)=0$

However after calculating v(1) = 811.25 ( which is already wrong compared to a true value of around 9 ) , the terms under the square root always evaluate to a negative value.

What could I have done wrong here?

Edit: 
Since I have a quadratic in v, I used the quadratic formula to solve for it and I got:
$$v(x_i) = \frac{ \frac{1}{\Delta x} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{\Delta x}^2 - 4(c/m)(v(x_{i-1}) -g)}} {2\cdot c/m } $$

Which still does not work for small values of $\Delta x$.

Any tips/ help are really appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Solve it exactly!

Comment: Note that the expression for $v(x_i)$ in terms of $v(x_{i-1})$ is quadratic in $v(x_{i-1})$ so it has in general two possible solutions. For your initial condition $v(0) = 0$, this implies that for small $t$, $v'(t)$ is approximately $-g$ which is negative so $v(t)$ should be negative, not positive. If you will take the negative square root, it might fix things. It is also possible that you have made an error in the simplification of the formula for $v(x_i)$ in terms of $v(x_{i-1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}t}=\frac{c}{m}v(t)^2-g\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$v'(t)=\frac{cv(t)^2}{m}-g\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{v'(t)}{\frac{cv(t)^2}{m}-g}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{v'(t)}{\frac{cv(t)^2}{m}-g}\space\text{d}t=\int1\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{v'(t)}{\frac{cv(t)^2}{m}-g}\space\text{d}t=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $u=v(t)$ and $\text{d}u=v'(t)\space\text{d}t$:

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\frac{cu^2}{m}-g}\space\text{d}u=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int-\frac{1}{g\left(1-\frac{cu^2}{gm}\right)}\space\text{d}u=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{1}{g}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{cu^2}{gm}}\space\text{d}u=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $s=\frac{u\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{gm}}$ and $\text{d}s=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{gm}}\space\text{d}u$:

---

$$-\sqrt{\frac{m}{cg}}\int\frac{1}{1-s^2}\space\text{d}s=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\sqrt{\frac{m}{cg}}\text{arctanh}(s)=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{\sqrt{m}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{v(t)\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{g}\sqrt{m}}\right)}{\sqrt{c}\sqrt{g}}=t+\text{k}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$v(t)=\frac{\sqrt{gm}\tanh\left(\frac{\text{k}-t\sqrt{cg}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)}{\sqrt{c}}$$

With the condition that $v(0)=0$ we find $v(t)$:

$$v(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{gm}\tanh\left(\frac{t\sqrt{cg}}{\sqrt{m}}\right)}{\sqrt{c}}$$

Comment: Thank you for this. It's still very weird how bad the numerical approximation is to this problem....

Comment: @CivilSigma Notice, that we have negative velocity because you're moving down

Comment: I solved it!! The numerical approximation turned out to be very very very close to the real answer!! It's very cool :D

Comment: @CivilSigma wow, nice! You're welcome.